# Failed to print the expected result

Tags: c

***Question:*** There are five kinds of scholarship, there is no limit to the number of scholarships awarded, and each student can receive multiple scholarships at the same time. I have to calculate each student's scholarship.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[21];
    int score1;
    int score2;
    char leader;
    char west;
    int paper;
    int sum;
};
int main(void)
{
    struct Student stu[100];
    int money_get(struct Student stu[],int m);
    int i,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);   //n is the number of student
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  //input every student's information
    {
        scanf("%s %d %d %c %c %d",stu[i].name,&stu[i].score1,&stu[i].score2,&stu[i].leader,&stu[i].west,&stu[i].paper);
        stu[i].sum=money_get(&stu[i],i);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)    //output every student's name and their scholarship
        printf("%-21s%d\n",stu[i].name,stu[i].sum);
    return 0;
}

int money_get(struct Student stu[],int m)
{
    int money;
    money=0;

    //the conditons of the five scholarship

    if(stu[m].score1>85&&stu[m].score2>80)    
        money+=4000;
    if(stu[m].score1>80&&stu[m].paper>0)
        money+=8000;
    if(stu[m].score1>90)
        money+=2000;
    if(stu[m].score1>85&&stu[m].west=='Y')
        money+=1000;
    if(stu[m].score2>80&&stu[m].leader=='Y')
        money+=850;
    return money;
}
```

The input is:

```
4
Tom 87 82 Y N 0
Jack 88 78 N Y 1
Jane 92 88 N N 0
Bob 83 87 Y N 1
```

The output is supposed to be:

```
Tom 4850
Jack 9000
Jane 6000
Bob 8850
```

But it is:

```
Tom 4850
Jack 0
Jane 2000
Bob 2000
```

It only works for the first student. Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: does this code even compile? `int money_get(struct Student stu[],int m);` shouldn't be in the body of `main`.

Comment: You are calling the function with `money_get(&stu[i],i);`, so it gets a pointer to the struct you want to handle (not the whole array) and in the function you index it again. So you have the index doubled. Just replace all `stu[m].` with `stu->`.

Answer (score 2):

### Your problem

You are passing `&stu[i]` to `money_get()`:

```
stu[i].sum = money_get(&stu[i], i);
```

So you pass a pointer to `stu[i]` as argument, but then, in `money_get()`, you do `stu[m]` where `stu` is already pointer to `stu[i]`.

### Solution

- `money_get()` should only take a pointer to a single `Student` as argument.
- Then `stu[m].` can be replaced by `stu->`.

Example:

```
int money_get(struct Student *stu)
{
    int money = 0;

    if (stu->score1 > 85 && stu->score2 > 80)    
        money += 4000;
    if (stu->score1 > 80 && stu->paper > 0)
        money += 8000;
    if (stu->score1 > 90)
        money += 2000;
    if (stu->score1 > 85 && stu->west == 'Y')
        money += 1000;
    if (stu->score2 > 80 && stu->leader == 'Y')
        money += 850;
    return money;
}
```

You can call this version of `money_get()` like this:

```
stu[i].sum = money_get(&stu[i]);
```